# Problems with resizing HTML text/element

Tags: css, html

Then I want to put two texts side by side and I did that by setting the `width` and `display: inline-block`.

The problem is that when I resize the page in Chrome, instead of staying in center, the blocks of text float left the more you resize.

I tried changing margins, paddings to auto or custom, I tried putting a wrapper but in no way I can make them not move. I found stuff about resizing but every topic had an own example which wouldn't work with my site.

```css
.contactnumber {
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: 100;
}
#condesc {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: 100;
}
.pcontactnumber {
 position: inherit;
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.adresa {
 position: inherit;
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: 100;
}
.padresa {
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 width: 640px;
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="condesc" style="width: 615px">Phone numbers</h3>
<h4 class="adresa">Adress:</h4>
<p class="padresa">Rruga (this is my address), x/a, Prizren 20040</p>
<p class="pcontactnumber" style="width: 163px">049/xxx-yyy</p>
<p class="pcontactnumber" style="width: 160px">049/yyy-xxx</p>
<p class="pcontactnumber" style="width: 153px">044/xyx-yxy</p>
```

This is beginner stuff but I just started on HTML/CSS and this is my first proper project. Thanks!

Comment: And for some reason I didn't know how to post JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

How about a combination of media queries and `width: 50%` on each blocks?

```css
.contactnumber {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
#condesc {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.pcontactnumber {
  position: inherit;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.adresa {
  position: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.padresa {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 640px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .half {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="half">
  <h3 id="condesc">Phone numbers</h3>
  <p class="pcontactnumber" style="width: 163px">049/xxx-yyy</p>
  <p class="pcontactnumber" style="width: 160px">049/yyy-xxx</p>
  <p class="pcontactnumber" style="width: 153px">044/xyx-yxy</p>
</div>
<div class="half">
  <h3 class="adresa">Adress:</h3>
  <p class="padresa">Rruga (this is my address), x/a, Prizren 20040</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't work. It just moved the "Adress:" and put it under "Phone Numbers" and when I resized nothing happened

Comment: @Sh.z If you maximize your screen, you can see the two columns. Otherwise, if you use a mobile or a small table, you can see the phone numbers followed by the address ;)

Comment: I have it maximized on 1280x960 resolution, but as I said it just put it there

Comment: @Sh.z but... that is included in your webpage, there are other css / html elements that affect your code!

Answer (score 0):

Put all the text in one div and give it

```
div {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This should center the texts and keep them in the center

Comment: It didn't do the job. Same thing again

Answer (score 0):

You can try an option with the addition of div and property display:flex

```css
.contactnumber {
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: 100;
}
#condesc {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: 100;
}
.pcontactnumber {
 position: inherit;
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.adresa {
 position: inherit;
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: 100;
}
.padresa {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.phone {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-flex">
  <h3 id="condesc">Phone numbers</h3>
  <h4 class="adresa">Adress:</h4>
</div>
<div class="block-flex">
  <div class="phone">
    <p class="pcontactnumber">049/xxx-yyy</p>
    <p class="pcontactnumber">049/yyy-xxx</p>
    <p class="pcontactnumber">044/xyx-yxy</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="padresa">Rruga (this is my address), x/a, Prizren 20040</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The address gets put under the phone number and it still goes left.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you start learninig HTML/CSS, here is some tips regarding CSS:

1 - classes (like '.my-class') are meant to be reusable, so I encourage you to regroup reusable CSS rules into one or several classes and add this classes to all elements that share the same parameters rather then reapeat the same rules on each class.

Remember you can add multiples classes to a single element.

If you need specific CSS rules for a specific elemnt, when use an "id", dedicated to this element.

It will be way more easy to maintain on the long run.

2 - Try to avoid adding CSS rules to elements using the style attribut. It's not a good idea because you mix things (structure : HTML with layout/design: CSS). And it can be confusion for the browsers.

3 - Try the [mobile first](http://www.alphansotech.com/blogs/what-is-mobile-first-design-why-its-so-important-in-2016/) approach when you want your layout to be responsive. Basically, you just start designing for the smallest device then add rules to update how element should be displayed via [media query](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Here is an exemple on how you can create a simple "grid" that display all elements as a list, then reorder them when on larger screens.

You can take a look at CSS frameworks like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which offert that type of structure along with many others.

```css
body {
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.row {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}

.col-12, 
.col-13, 
.col-14, 
.col-34 {
 margin-left: 1%;
 margin-right: 1%;
 widht: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

 .row div {
  float: left;
 }

 .col-12 {
  width: 48%;
 }

 .col-13 {
  width: 31%;
 }

 .col-14 {
  width: 23%;
 }

 .col-34 {
  width: 73%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  <h3>Phone numbers</h3>
  <p><strong>049/xxx-yyy</strong></p>
  <p><strong>049/yyy-xxx</strong></p>
  <p><strong>044/xyx-yxy</strong></p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-12">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-14">
    <h4 class="address">Adress:</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="col-34">
    <p class="">Rruga (this is my address), x/a, Prizren 20040</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was the closest I went to my goal, but still phone numbers float left. http://i.imgur.com/iU67iBs.png

Comment: Can you post the entire source of the page (HTML + CSS)? Maybe some other CSS rules interfere.

Comment: Thanks @Dexter0015 but I changed completely the way how I wanted it to look. It was probably because of my poor coding. Thanks :)